# Azure Devops create work item and add to sprint via rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to create a new work item with the following command:

```
az boards work-item create --title Test  --type Task --project <project name>  --assigned-to <user email> --fields "Description=PR is open, please test the new exe version and approve Priority=2"
```

The command is running inside a pipeline, and it is working.

However I want the work item to be inside the current running sprint.
Any idea how and if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

According to [az boards work-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#az-boards-work-item-create), you could try to use the --iteration parameters to add the workitem to the specific iteration to the sprint.

```
az boards work-item create --title Test  --type Task --project <project name>  --assigned-to <user email> --iteration TestProject\Sprint1 --fields "Description=PR is open, please test the new exe version and approve Priority=2"
```

For more information about iteartion, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-iterations-and-set-iteration-dates).

Comment: Does it meet your requirement？

Comment: Have you tried this command to check if it works?